# Close threads in order to create new ones?

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to send data over an MQTT connection and start a new thread every time I generate a set of data and send it (on one of 8 sensors). After that this thread should be closed, because I do not need it anymore.

```
def send_on_sensor(q, delay, pub):

    # I create a queue for each sensor
    while q.empty is not True:
        payload = json.dumps(q.get())
        pub.publish(payload)
        time.sleep(delay)

    return            # should the thread not close itself at return?


def send_dataset(secs=0):
    qs = []
    for i in range(8):
        qs.append(queue.Queue())

    for id in range(1000):
        msg = {
            "id": id,
        }

        # assign c accordingly

        qs[c].put(msg)

    # I have a MQTT publisher client for every q, which will be reused

    for q in qs:
        index = qs.index(q)
        pub = publishers[index]
        t = threading.Thread(target=send_on_sensor, args=(q, secs, pub))
        t.daemon = True            # I dont know if this actually helps here?
        t.start()
        time.sleep(secs)


while True:
    send_dataset(output_interval)

    time.sleep(output_interval * 200)
```

I get this error, when I run the code after some time when I have created a few hundred threads:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users//PycharmProjects//V3_multiTops/mt_GenPub.py", line 303, in <module>
    send_dataset(X, y, output_interval)
  File "/Users//PycharmProjects//V3_multiTops/mt_GenPub.py", line 127, in send_dataset
    t.start()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 847, in start
    _start_new_thread(self._bootstrap, ())
RuntimeError: can't start new thread
```

How can I go about this error? How exactly to I close the thread, when I dont need it any further? Is it maybe even a bad architecture to have so many threads running and should I rewrite the program to use a fixed thread for each `q` (queue) with the corresponding `pub` (publisher)?

If so, how can I hand the newly generated data to the responsible thread?

Comment: You forgot to actually call `empty`, and you shouldn't use `empty` anyway - it's completely unsafe.

Comment: What about using a `ThreadPool`, there you can work with a fixed number of threads and reuse them as well

Comment: @user2357112 how do I "actually" call `empty`? I do `while q.empty is not True:` ...

Comment: could I maybe call `sys.exit()` from within the threaded method?

Comment: Ditto what @yorodm said:  Continually creating and destroying threads is an anti-pattern.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool  Doesn't seem to be one ready-made in the Python standard library, but you probably can find one on the interwebs, and if not, it isn't too hard to roll your own.